# AWS Glue job to unzip a file from S3 and write it back to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm very new to AWS Glue, and I want to use AWS Glue to unzip a huge file present in a S3 bucket, and write the contents back to S3.

I couldn't find anything while trying to google this requirement.

My questions are:

1. How to add a zip file as data source to AWS Glue?
2. How to write it back to same S3 location?

I am using AWS Glue Studio. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't find anything while trying to google this requirement.

You couldn't find anything about this, because **this is not what Glue does**. Glue can read `gzip` (not `zip`) files natively. If you have `zip`, then you have to convert all the files yourself in S3. Glue will not do it.

To convert the files, you can download them, re-pack, and re-upload in `gzip` format, or any other format that Glue supports.

Answer (score 5):

If you are still looking for a solution. You're able to unzip a file and write it back with an AWS Glue Job by using `boto3` and Python's `zipfile` library.

A thing to consider is the size of the zip that you want to process. I've used the following script with a **6GB (zipped) 30GB (unzipped)** file and it works fine. But might fail if the file is to heavy for the worker to buffer.

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

import boto3
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

bucket = "wayfair-datasource" # your s3 bucket name
prefix = "files/location/" # the prefix for the objects that you want to unzip
unzip_prefix = "files/unzipped_location/" # the location where you want to store your unzipped files 

# Get a list of all the resources in the specified prefix
objects = s3.list_objects(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix=prefix
)["Contents"]

# The following will get the unzipped files so the job doesn't try to unzip a file that is already unzipped on every run
unzipped_objects = s3.list_objects(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix=unzip_prefix
)["Contents"]

# Get a list containing the keys of the objects to unzip
object_keys = [ o["Key"] for o in objects if o["Key"].endswith(".zip") ] 
# Get the keys for the unzipped objects
unzipped_object_keys = [ o["Key"] for o in unzipped_objects ] 

for key in object_keys:
    obj = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="wayfair-datasource",
        Key=key
    )
    
    objbuffer = io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read())
    
    # using context manager so you don't have to worry about manually closing the file
    with ZipFile(objbuffer) as zip:
        filenames = zip.namelist()

        # iterate over every file inside the zip
        for filename in filenames:
            with zip.open(filename) as file:
                filepath = unzip_prefix + filename
                if filepath not in unzipped_object_keys:
                    s3.upload_fileobj(file, bucket, filepath)

job.commit()
```

Comment: This script worked like a charm. Thank you!